# Google places api doesn't return reviews or ratings

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-places-api

Something I just noticed is that our google+ page is https://plus.google.com/101505653197189425411/about

but the google+ page returned by the api is
https://plus.google.com/118350519387987879004/about?hl=en-US

both google plus pages are for our company I'm not sure what the second google+ page is but it does not have any reviews so that makes sense why there aren't any reviews returned from the api.

We would like to show some of our google reviews on the website for our company but I can only get information about our company, no ratings or reviews are returned. We have reviews on our google+ page as well as reviews that come up for us in a google search so I know we have reviews. I'm trying to use the google places api.  I did the places search to get a reference, I turned on the places api in the console, generated a key in the api access and set up some IPs to allow. I use curl to make the call.

```
  $request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CoQBegAAANKTKgF4XccOIERYeXixRttRcupjpiAnouwQJIqlPcM9BrFlHGMI2Css2lUhTfVVut65SCYB4CVxnMzk3hro24fijoTO15Fk7GWpqv9cgu7A0MltCVa1vNk6RrH8_5LRcea7u2LgbWtb5N6G109eif3ifOHzf09lTE1OdNIPR57qEhBkD6dtfnctIEd5IQEEW8RDGhRT0wWXkqYMtqJ2h901WR9kdWOKdw&sensor=false&key=supersecretapikey';

  $session = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  $response = curl_exec($session);
  //echo curl_getinfo($session). '<br/>';
  //echo curl_errno($session). '<br/>';
  //echo curl_error($session). '<br/>';
  curl_close($session);
  var_dump($response);
```

this is what is dumped from $response

```
  {
"debug_info": [],
"html_attributions": [],
"result": {
    "address_components": [
        {
            "long_name": "2805",
            "short_name": "2805",
            "types": [
                "street_number"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Washington Boulevard",
            "short_name": "Washington Boulevard",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Ogden",
            "short_name": "Ogden",
            "types": [
                "sublocality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Ogden",
            "short_name": "Ogden",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Weber County",
            "short_name": "Weber County",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "UT",
            "short_name": "UT",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "US",
            "short_name": "US",
            "types": [
                "country",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "84401",
            "short_name": "84401",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "2805 Washington Boulevard, Ogden, UT, United States",
    "formatted_phone_number": "(801) 621-6500",
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 41.213974,
            "lng": -111.970847
        }
    },
    "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
    "id": "ce471d4942919106311349a18d805be7046a61bf",
    "international_phone_number": "+1 801-621-6500",
    "name": "Hertz Car Sales Ogden UT",
    "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true,
        "periods": [
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 1,
                    "time": "2000"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 1,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            },
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 2,
                    "time": "2000"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 2,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            },
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 3,
                    "time": "2000"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 3,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            },
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 4,
                    "time": "2000"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 4,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            },
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 5,
                    "time": "2000"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 5,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            },
            {
                "close": {
                    "day": 6,
                    "time": "1900"
                },
                "open": {
                    "day": 6,
                    "time": "0900"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "reference": "CoQBegAAAKS_lTlHVHEBg4mUzeFpsO1VDcHdnQ0GVgGezJ-TaHbFnsvGYqvh-Yzuc1N6UF0lQQuJM0IWa1BIWmbXbs5Yvj7mhBgTph0u5ResZhFYDYSXi5q6RIlRfe1Vlj40DoHroLmAAmbfaghv-TQV7a7VH3QlOckSaCiuMwkpWX6tOGd-EhDPycK7dnAJZxnq5Jx2Tz00GhR98Y2mAkoL68NlnL-uyFeld1RvbQ",
    "types": [
        "establishment"
    ],
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/118350519387987879004/about?hl=en-US",
    "utc_offset": -420,
    "vicinity": "2805 Washington Boulevard, Ogden",
    "website": "http://www.hertzogden.com/"
},
"status": "OK"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with us having more than one google plus page for the same location in google places.

Comment: Thanks. Been puzzling over this rating element omission for ages.